# Lock entire Dictionary or part of before copying (SyncRoot)

Tags: c#, multithreading, blazor, thread-safety, syncroot

I have 2 dictionaries in a scoped service within a Blazor server application I use to manage state for multi tenancy. It has come to my attention that there may be concurrency issues with users modifying the dictionaries on different threads.

```
public Dictionary<string, GlobalDataModel> Global { get; } = new();
public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<long, LocalDataModel>> Local { get; } = new();
```

I think I'm leaning towards leaving these as normal dictionaries and locking sync root when modifying or iterating over.

If I were to add an item to a collection within the containing class, would it be:

```
if (Local.ContainsKey(tenantId) == false)
{
    lock (syncRoot)
    {
        Local.Add(tenantId, new Dictionary<long, LocalDataModel>());
    }
}
```

or:

```
lock (syncRoot)
{
    if (Local.ContainsKey(tenantId) == false)
    {
        {
            Local.Add(tenantId, new Dictionary<long, LocalDataModel>());
        }
    }
}
```

Then if I were to copy different parts of the service collection to lists from an external class so it can be safely iterated would I just lock at the Service level, the Dictionary level, or the DataModel level, or is it dependent?

Say I wanted a resources collection within a specific project.  Would it be:

```
[Inject] private IDataAdaptor DataAdaptor { get; set; };
var resources;
    
lock (DataAdaptor)
{
    resources = DataAdaptor.Local[TenantId][ProjectId].Resources;
}
```

or:

```
lock (DataAdaptor.Local[TenantId][ProjectId].Resources)
{
   resources = DataAdaptor.Local[TenantId][ProjectId].Resources;
}
```

And vice versa for different parts of the collection, et Tenants, Projects etc...

I assume I have to lock on the object because `syncRoot` isn't accessible outside the containing class, or do I create a `SyncRoot` object in the class where I'm copying and lock on that?

Obviously multi threading is a new concept.

Comment: Why can't you use `ConcurrentDictionary`?

Comment: I looked at concurrent dictionary and in this case i will still have the same issue that it could be updated while someone is iterating and also had a problem prefilling on load for reasons too involved for this post

Comment: Syncroot is an object in my 'DataAdaptor' service/class... public object syncRoot = new();

Comment: I may have inadvertently called my service a DataAdapter though it does not use the System.Data.Common though it does have similarities

Comment: If reads are often but writes are rare - consider also using `ReaderWriterLockSlim`. Then you can have multiple simultaneous readers while there are no writes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` [is thread-safe only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2#thread-safety) when used by multiple readers and zero writers. As soon as you add a writer in the mix, in other words if the dictionary is not frozen and can be mutated, then it is thread-safe for nothing. Every access to the dictionary, even the slightest touch like reading its `Count`, should be synchronized, otherwise its behavior is undefined.

Synchronizing a dictionary can be quite inefficient, especially if you have to enumerate it and do something with each of its entries. In this case you have to either create a copy of the dictionary (`.ToArray()`) and enumerate the copy, or `lock` for the whole duration of the iteration, blocking all other threads that might want to do trivial reads or writes. Alternative collections that are better suited for multithreaded environments are the [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2) and the [`ImmutableDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2).

In case you want to educate yourself systematically about thread-safety, here is an online resource: [Threading in C# - Thread Safety](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Thread_Safety) by Joseph Albahari.

Comment: Thank you for the reply,  i had looked at ConcurrentDictionary, however on testing it seemed there was still the chance that it could change while another thread was iterating?  I also had an issue filling it on the initial load. maybe i will go revisit it.  I was aiming to copy, i only need certain parts at any one time so can copy to list easy enough and then iterate etc. And thankyou for the link to thread safety I will read in detail.

Comment: @Pippo I don't know how you used the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>`, but keep in mind that its thread-safety is limited to itself, and it is not extended to the values it contains. So if for example the `TValue` is `List<T>`, and the lists are changed by multiple threads concurrently, you'll have to synchronize each list independently.

Comment: So when updating a TValue as a list do you lock on the list that is being updated or the dictionary

Comment: @Pippo you lock on the list, to minimize the contention. This way other threads will not be blocked, unless they try to mutate the same list. Btw be aware that the `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>` is not an easy class to handle. It has a number of non-obvious traps to fall in, and everyone one is falling in them until they master the class.

Comment: Thanks, probably why I couldn’t get it working how I wanted with my initial attempt

Comment: So locking on a syncRoot object prevents the same block of code being run in deferent threads.  But if I lock on List<T> that will prevent mutation of the list until the lock is released even if from another thread in the same class or a different thread and different block of code in a different class? Ie not only locking access to a block of code  that modifies the list but also locking the list so it can’t be edited?  Conceptualising this is proving difficult and I need it spelled out apparently.

Comment: @Pippo the thread-safety of the `List<T>` is similar to the thread-safety of the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. If it's used by readers and writers concurrently, it must be synchronized meticulously everywhere, otherwise its behavior is undefined. Synchronized means that only one thread at a time should be allowed to interact with the list.

Comment: Will lock(List<T>) {…} prevent that list being mutated by another thread while the subsequent code block runs?

Comment: @Pippo if the other thread is mutating the list without first entering a `lock`-protected region using the same object as locker, then no, the `lock(List<T>)` on the current thread won't prevent the other thread from mutating the list. Locking is cooperative. It cannot be enforced from one thread to another, in a non-cooperative manner.

Comment: Gottya just use same object as locker. Thanks for patience explaining.